# Extract array in nested JSON object with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to extract an array from a `JSON` object with `MYSQL`

```
SELECT json_extract(jsonObjectValue,'$[*].name') as array FROM `TEST` WHERE name='jsonObject'
```

The query above has this as a result

```
...
["elem1", "elem1", "elem2"]
["elem5", "elem1", "elem2", "elem4"]
...
```

I tried doing to extract the array by doing this:

```
SELECT json_extract(json_extract(jsonObjectValue,'$[*].name'),'$[*]') as array FROM `TEST` WHERE name='jsonObject'
```

The desired result would look like this:

```
...
"elem1"
"elem1"
"elem2"
"elem5"
"elem1"
"elem2"
"elem4"
...
```

but the actual result is:

```
...
["elem1", "elem1", "elem2"]
["elem5", "elem1", "elem2", "elem4"]
...
```

I also tried to change `'$[*]'` inside the JSON extract to `'$[0]'` it only shows the first element of the array.

**Update**

to **reproduce** the issue run these queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST` (
`jsonObjectValue` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

and for the data run:

```
INSERT INTO `TEST` (`jsonObjectValue`, `name`) VALUES
('[{\"name\":\"elem1\"},{\"name\":\"elem1\"},{\"name\":\"elem2\"}]', 
'JsonObject'),
('test', 'name'),
('test2', 'test2'),
('[{\"name\":\"elem5\"},{\"name\":\"elem1\"},{\"name\":\"elem2\"}, 
{\"name\":\"elem4\"}]', 'jsonObject');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL version????

Comment: the version is `MySQL 5`

Comment: You're out of options I am afraid. A brute force approach that uses `$[x].name` as path where x comes from a table of numbers 0...999 might work.

Comment: Priovide a fiddle with some sample data (or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts).

Comment: *the version is MySQL 5* Treate intermediate array as a string, and parse it using common string functions and generated numbers table.

Comment: @Akina you can check out the CREATE script and INSERT INTO and thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrays.array, ',', numbers.num), ',', -1)) element
FROM ( SELECT TRIM('[' FROM TRIM(']' FROM json_extract(jsonObjectValue,'$[*].name'))) as array 
       FROM `TEST` 
       WHERE name='jsonObject') arrays,
     ( SELECT 1 num UNION ALL
       SELECT 2 UNION ALL
       SELECT 3 UNION ALL
       SELECT 4 UNION ALL
       SELECT 5 ) numbers
WHERE numbers.num <= LENGTH(arrays.array) - LENGTH(REPLACE(arrays.array, ',', '')) + 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4ac2c45d038120b8b251f0ec64a8fb81)

PS. The amount of numbers generated must be not less than the max amount of elements in separate array - if not some values will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Akina this is far too complicated, and I'm only solving part of the problem,  The final result would way too large to implement...

Comment: @KamelMili Update your MySQL to last version, and use JSON_TABLE() function.